# Word and Excel with Macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I tried to make a easy code that takes a value out of an Excel sheet and writes it (with replacement) in a given Word template with a VBA Macro.

If I run this code it says that the Object WordContent is not defined.

If I delete this line it says that the variable wdFindContinue is not definded and thus crashes. Since I am a beginner in VBA and I copied this code out of the internet I do not know how to handle this problem

Could somebody pls help

```
Sub myfirstprogram()
Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow, DaysSince, FrDays, ToDays As Long    
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
Dim WordContent As Word.Range

With Tabelle1
    CustRow = .Range("A1").Value
    DocLoc = Tabelle1.Range("I2").Value 'Word Document Filename
                            'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Launch a new instance of Word
    Err.Clear
    'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
    
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
    TagName = .Cells("C1").Value
    TagValue = .Cells("C" & CustRow).Value
    With WordDoc.Content.Find
        .Text = TagName
        .Replacement.Text = TagValue
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'replace every instance
    End With
    
    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("C" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf"
    WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
    WordDoc.Close False ' i close it and do not save it
    
    WordApp.Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When declaring multiple variables on the same line, you need to know that the variable type need to be specified for each variable, else the default type `Variant` will be applied. For example, in `Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow, DaysSince, FrDays, ToDays As Long` only `ToDays` is of type `Long`, the others are `Variant`s.

Comment: I'm guessing you did not add Word library in your reference. `Tools` -> `References`, look for Microsoft Word and check it.

Comment: If the above works and you prefer not to add reference (aka late-binding) then declare `Dim WordContent As Object` and replace `wdFindContinue` to 1 ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfindwrap)),  `wdReplaceAll` to 2 ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdreplace)) and `wdExportFormatPDF` to 17 ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportformat])). These are enumeration that only exist in Word library and if you do not add it as your reference, you need to provide its numerical value instead.

Comment: @RaymondWu Why don't you write it as an answer? That is actually what's wrong with the code. And your comment solves it.

Comment: I'll check back later and post an answer if that is all the issues, typing on phone so it's hard to confirm that's the issue (but you confirmed it!) and I'm quite sure there's a duplicate answer somewhere...@Pᴇʜ

Comment: Also there is probably a `End If` missing before `WordApp.Visible = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring variable to a specific object type that only exist in a library requires you to have its reference added (in this case its `Microsoft Word #.0 Object Library`).

Since you have declare `WordContent` as `Word.Range`, usage of enum such as `wdFindContinue`, `wdReplaceAll` and `wdExportFormatPDF` that is only available in Word library in your code, VBA attempts to find the object/enum but fails because you did not have Word library added in your reference so to solve this you can add the reference in `Tools` -> `References` and check the appropriate library. (Aka early-binding)

If you prefers your code to work without Word library added to your reference (aka late-binding), you will then need to declare variables as Object and use the numerical representation of the enum.

`Dim WordContent As Word.Range` -> `Dim WordContent As Object` (Though you might as well delete it as nowhere in the code did you `Set` or use `WordContent`)

`wdFindContinue` = 1 ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfindwrap))

`wdReplaceAll` = 2 ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdreplace))

`wdExportFormatPDF` = 17 ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportformat%5D))

And lastly, as noted by Vincent G, you are missing an `End If` before `WordApp.Visible = True`

As to whether to use early-binding or late-binding, you can read [this](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/early_vs_late_binding.html) for your own reference.